# How to end/clear/terminate a function starting after interval BEFORE the interval is over?

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval, exit, delayed-execution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onmouseup="end()">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>


<script>
var counter;
var count = 0;

window.onload=function()
{
var x=document.getElementsByClassName('banana')
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
    let y=x[i];     //////////hier funktioniert es nicht mit var !!!
    
    console.log(y);
        x[i].onmousedown = debounce(function()
        {
        start(y.className,y.value.replace(/\s/g, ''));
        }, 550);
    }
}


function debounce(a, b)
{
    var timer; 
    return function()
    {
        clearTimeout(timer); 
        timer = setTimeout(function()
        {
            a(); 
        }, b); 
    };
}

function start(clicked_className,cha)
  {
    counter = setInterval(function()
    {
      add(clicked_className,cha);
      count++;
    },90);
  }
  function end()
  {
  clearInterval(counter);
  }

function add(clicked_className,cha)
{
window.document.numeri.outpu.value =
window.document.numeri.outpu.value + cha;


}

</script>
<style>
#put
{
    width:700px;
    height:18px;
    font-size=14pt;
}
</style>

<body>
<form name="numeri">
<input type="text" id="put"name="outpu">
<input type="button"id="apple"class="banana"value="  1  "onmouseleave="end()">
<input type="button"id="ada"class="banana"value="  2  "onmouseleave="end()">
<input type="button"id="aded"class="banana"value=" 3  "onmouseleave="end()">

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

It starts after an Interval, but doesnt clear the interval if the conditions for terminating/clearing are met before the interval even started.

Now its like this:
Press button->550ms Waiting time->function->termination if conditions met

But it has to work like this too:
Press button->550ms Waiting time->termination if conditions met->no function

I have no idea how to fix that please help me :(

Also maybe is there a better way to do it in the first place?

Comment: Remove     var timer; 
 from the function scope.

Comment: how exactly  ? where to put it?